# How to filter search result in few specific columns when having multiple fields in a dataset in Ng-table(angularJS)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I'm using ngTable with many fields(25), I want to restrict my search filter in a few fields. Do we have something like filter options or so where we can pass what fields of dataset that needs to be filtered in search?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom filter to the table search using NgTableParams. For example, if you want to filter based on a specific value ( eg a letter value), you can add something like this in the controller:

```
 this.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
  // initial filter
  filter: { name: "T" } 
}, {
  dataset: simpleList
});
```

You can check this codepen for reference with a full example : [ngtable filter example](https://codepen.io/christianacca/pen/jPRMVY)

Comment: Thanks @dituoa. the solution you provide is for filtering the data set.
I am looking for a solution using which i can restrict my dataset in NgTableParams.
For ex. i have 12 fields in my data set, but i am only showing 4 out of 12 in my table.
while searching in search box, the result is filtered for all 12 fields of my data set. which is giving irrelevant search result on UI. i want to restrict my data set in ngTableParam, so that my search filter can be done only on viewing data(4 fields in complete dataset)